# Adding CI for overall column in gtsummary (tbl_summary) creates error

Tags: r, gtsummary

I'm trying to create a summary table with tbl_summary showing the mean(sd) + 95%CI for both groups and also for the overall sample.

To get the CI for the overall column, I figures out that I need to put the add_overall command before add_ci. For any reason, it does lead to an error that I can't solve. What needs to be changed?

```
summary_table <- df %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = group,
    include = sus_score,
    type = sus_score ~ "continuous",
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 2,
    statistic =
      all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})"
    )%>%
  add_overall() %>%
  add_ci(statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "[{conf.low} - {conf.high}]"))%>%
  add_p(all_continuous() ~ "t.test")
```

The error it shows is:

> Error in `map()`:
> In index: 1.
> Caused by error in `all_of()`:
> Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> Column `ci_stat_0` doesn't exist.
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.